MAUI Project: Error code: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFB] Another user has already installed an unpackaged version of this app
I have a project I'm trying to deploy. However, I'm running into the following error code:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFB] Another user has already installed an unpackaged version of this app. The current user cannot replace this with a packaged version. The conflicting package is 5d07e08d-711a-4322-b166-e9ab8eaec42a and it was published by CN=User Name. MonEraMauiOperatorInterface
I've looked around and figured that running the following line on Powershell on Admin access would be the best solution:
remove-appxpackage -Package 5d07e08d-711a-4322-b166-e9ab8eaec42a_1.0.0.1_x64__9zz4h110yvjzm -AllUsers

where 5d07e08d-711a-4322-b166-e9ab8eaec42a_1.0.0.1_x64__9zz4h110yvjzm is the PackageFullName that I got from running the following line on Powershell on Admin access:
get-appxpackage -name 5d07e08d-711a-4322-b166-e9ab8eaec42a -AllUsers
However, I keep getting the error message remote procedure call failed. When I look at the logs, I see the following entries:
Started deployment Remove operation on a package with main parameter 5d07e08d-711a-4322-b166-e9ab8eaec42a_1.0.0.1_x64__9zz4h110yvjzm and Options 0 and 0. See http://go.microsoft.c
                                       om/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

Identified 2 request(s) in the Queue Store for potential restoration.

Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\1e15fbe8-7ddf-4e03-bde4-a4dcbb452612_S-1-5-21-1596155269-1285879985-3340332096-279643_1.rslc for Remove Ope
                                       ration on Package 5d07e08d-711a-4322-b166-e9ab8eaec42a_1.0.0.1_x64__9zz4h110yvjzm.

I thought that maybe the remove-appxpackage makes a request to the Windows server (?) and then proceeds with the deletion, which would explain the error since my work laptop has a lot of network restrictions. Regardless, I'm at a point where I need to remove the package, but cannot do so using the powershell command. At this point, I'm not sure what to do, and would appreciate any guidance.

Refer to this case: Registration of the app failed error in Windows Store or Universal app.

@JianweiSun-MSFT thank you very much for the link. Renaming the package in Package.appxmanifest did the trick. If you can leave the link as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Well, as an answer:

MAUI Project: Error code: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFB] Another user has already installed an unpackaged version of this app

About this error, renaming the package in Package.appxmanifest can fix it.
For more details can refer to this case: Registration of the app failed error in Windows Store or Universal app.
